# Limiting UITextField to 2 digits representing a month

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I've created a view controller that allows a person to enter their credit card information to continue with a purchase. All is good except the pesky year & month formatting. More specifically the month, where it's required the user only be able to input 2 digits (which was easy to do with the 'shouldChangeCharactersInRange' method) plus some sort of check that limits what kind of numbers can be left in the UITextField. Currently, the user can type any 2 digits inside (looks like this inside the text field: 83 or 21 etc.) but I need only digits from 1-12 being allowed.

While looking around stack overflow I was sure someone has done something like this but I haven't been able to find anything. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

What would be placed inside?

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    switch (textField.tag)
    {
        case 3: //Month.
            //This allows to tap on a UITextField, even if it already contains 2 digits, and deleting these digits with the delete key with out being thrown out because of 'resignFirstResponder'.
            if (textField.text.length > 1 && !([string length] == 0 && range.length > 0))
            {
                [_textfieldMonth resignFirstResponder];
            }


            //End up with UITextField displaying only from 01 - 12.


            break;

        case 4: //Year.
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could always try a `intValue` on your string and check if it's between 1 and 12 ?

Comment: I'm actually trying that right now. If it works, I'll post the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check  `if/else` condition to check the input  `[yourTextField.text intValue] < 13 && [yourTextField.text intValue] > 0`, if it is bigger than 12 or less than 0 then issue an `alertview`.

```
if (textField.text.length > 1 && !([string length] == 0 && range.length > 0))
 {
      if([textField.text intValue]<13 &&[textField.text intValue]>0)
      {
        [_textfieldMonth resignFirstResponder];
      }
      else
      {
         UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please make sure you enter a value between 1-12" delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [message show];
      }
 }
```

In adidition to that, if you further convert the user input to the month name if needed as follows:

```
int monthNumber = textField.text; 
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *monthName = [[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(monthNumber-1)];
```

Comment: It should also check if it's > 0.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. If the user types in a single digit number it will show the alert. If the user types in `12`, it will show the alert.

Comment: I have modified my answer a little bit, sorry I did not test it, but I just thought to guide.

Comment: It's still all wrong. Change `12` to `13` had nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Still wrong. Please stop guessing. Get something that actually works and then update your answer. As written now, If I enter the letter `A`, it will be accepted.

Comment: Sorry I do not have facility (mac operating system) to check all test scenarios, I just want to guide him in the right direction. That is what he wanted in his question `right direction`. He is free to uncheck my answer and accept your answer, I do not mind.

Comment: OK but the code in your answer is not guiding in the right direction. Sorry but it's just a mess of incorrect, messy code that won't work in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code in your question (and the current code in the other answer) is that `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is called before the most recently typed/pasted/cut/copied text has actually been sent to the text field. You need to look at what the new text will be and validate that.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    switch (textField.tag)
    {
        case 3: //Month.
        {
            NSString *value = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
            int month = [value intValue];
            if (month >= 1 && month <= 12)
            {
                [textField resignFirstResponder];
            }
            break;
        }
        case 4: //Year.
            break;
    }
}
```

A better solution would be to wait to validate the month entry when the user actually tries to leave the month field and prevent them from leaving if the value is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did and it ended up working for my needs.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    switch (textField.tag)
    {
        case 3: //Month.
            if (textField.text.length > 1 && !([string length] == 0 && range.length > 0))
            {
                int intValue = [textField.text intValue];
                if (intValue < 13)
                {
                    [_textfieldMonth resignFirstResponder];
                }
                else
                {
                    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Month"];
                    [_textfieldMonth resignFirstResponder];

                    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"This field only accepts numbers from 01 to 12" delegate:self  cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
                    [message show];
                }
            }
            break;
        case 4: //Year.
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This can't work. If the month text field is blank and the user then types in the letter "A" then this code will accept the letter. Or if I've already typed in the number "3", for example, if I then type in any other character, this code will accept the out of range value. You really need test all kinds of invalid data including the user pasting in text. My answer solves all of these issues.

Comment: It really doesn't what? Work? Yes, I know it doesn't work in all cases. Not as written. Try it. Type "A". It lets the "A" in. You don't want that, do you?